# Approximation with "quantile-constraints"

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, approximation-algorithms

**Question:**

> given:
> $$\begin{align}&\phantom{=}\lbrace \left(x_i,y_i\right),\ x_i\in\mathbb{X}, y_i\in \mathbb{R}\rbrace_{i=1}^n\\
> &\phantom{=}f: (x\in\mathbb{X},\,p_1,\dots,\, p_k\in\mathbb{R})\mapsto y\in\mathbb{R}\\
> &\phantom{=}0\lt m\lt n\end{align}$$
>
> what is known about calculating the optimal parameters $\boldsymbol{p}^*:=p_1^*,\,\dots,\,p_k^*$ for which:
> $$\begin{align}\\
> &\left|\,\mathrm{card}\left(f(x_i,\boldsymbol{p}^*)\le y_i\right)-m\,\right|&\le&\quad\left|\mathrm{card}\left(f(x_i,\boldsymbol{p}')\le y_i\right)-m\,\right|&\\ \\
> &\left|\,\mathrm{card}\left(f(x_i,\boldsymbol{p}^*)\le y_i\right)-m\,\right|&=&\quad\left|\,\mathrm{card}\left(f(x_i,\boldsymbol{p}')\le y_i\right)-m\,\right|&\implies\\
> &\sum \|y_i-f(x_i,\boldsymbol{p}^*)\|^2&\le&\quad\sum \|y_i-f(x_i,\boldsymbol{p}')\|^2&\text{resp.}\\
> &\max \|y_i-f(x_i,\boldsymbol{p}^*)\|&\le&\quad\max \|y_i-f(x_i,\boldsymbol{p}')\|&
> \end{align}$$

A concrete setting of such a problem would be to find the best-approximating polynomial for which the same number of points lies above and below the otherwise best-approximating polynomial.